# How do I load a JavaScript function when I click on a window.open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i just need to call function in parent window while user is focusing on child window (popup). i have this code in my parent window,

```
<html> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function CallParent()
        {
            alert(" Parent window Alert");
        }
    </script>
    <body> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" NAME="My Window Name" title=" My title here " onClick=window.open("child.html","Ratting","width=550,height=170,0,status=0,");>Click here to open the child window</a>
    </body> 
</html>
```

and bellow code is in my child window,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
                window.opener.CallParent();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h2>This is Child window</h2> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

so..in this case i supposed that CallParent() will be fired just after child window is opened. but it seems to be not working. can any one give me any hints to make this script to work, or any better way to do this.

Comment: Did You try postMessage? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: nope, how can i use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `popup.html`, you can refer to `opener`, which is the window that opened it. The globals in that window are accessible to it, since the two windows are from the same origin. With your code as quoted, it can do this to call the function (when opened as a popup):

```
function closeWindow()
{
   window.opener.mainFunction();
   window.close();
}
```

then use this in button onclick on your child window

**EDIT**

Seems like your having hard time where to place the code, and how to use it so here, in your **popup.html**:

```
<script>
  function closeWindow()
  {
       window.opener.mainFunction();
       window.close();
  }
  $(window).load(function() {
      $("#button").click(function(){ closeWindow(); }); 
  });
</script>
<center>
    <input type="button" value="click me to continue" id="button"/>
</center>
```

just make sure that you have a jQuery library available in your popup.html.

The code above clearly says that on windows load jQuery will bind the closeWindow() function into #button onclick.

Comment: For an answer to be *useful*, it should *explain*, not just quote code. I've copied the explanation from my answer to yours and deleted mine.

Comment: @T.J Crowder sorry but i didnt deleted any answer or comment :c

Comment: it should be something like: (i know that its wrong but it is for explaination only xd) myWindow.$("#button").click(function(){ // some code});

Comment: $("#button").click(function(){   closeWindow();   });

Comment: @IsmaelGonzales: No, *you* didn't, I did. VMcreator and I posted answers at about the same time. Mine had an explanation, his/hers didn't. But he/she saw the bit about closing the window that I missed. So I deleted my answer and copied the explation here.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh sorry hahaha i get it xD i edited my question for better understanding, i did that code and not working, also tried changing window.opener with window.parent.mainFunction(); but also didnt worked :c also i wanted to thank all of you  guys for answering and reply (y)

Answer (score 0):

> nope, how can i use it?

You can test it on: http://test-humster.cba.pl/old_window.html

old_window.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <button onclick="openNewWindow()">open</button>
        <script>
            function openNewWindow(){
                window.open("new_windwo.html", "new tab");
            }

            window.addEventListener("message", function(data){
               try{
                   var jsonData = JSON.parse(data.data);
                   document.getElementById("body").setAttribute("style", "background: "+jsonData.color);
               }catch(e){}
            }, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

new_window.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="changeColor()">Change parent color</button>
        <script>
            function changeColor(){
                window.opener.postMessage('{"color":"red"}', "http://test-humster.cba.pl/old_window.html");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```